# Detecting `accountsChanged` and `chainChanged` with ethersjs?

Tags: events, clients, ethers.js

I'm not sure if this question makes sense or if I'm looking at things correctly but it's coming from my understanding that ethersjs is an abstraction on top of MetaMask (and other providers)...

I've been able to get events from `ethereum.on('chainChanged')` and `ethereum.on('accountsChanged')` but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this through the ethersjs events or interface.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jm42/ba60165ecbda76134e215080f46abff3

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any official document for that in https://docs.ethers.io/

The way I do is to listen to `chainChanged` event directly from external Web3provider.

`ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum).provider.on('chainChanged')`

`ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum).provider.on('accountsChanged')`

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link for different etherjs events and event types:

https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--event-methods

You can also check this link:
https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/providers/src.ts/base-provider.ts#L2047

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize ethers and set a provider variable

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
```

then you add/remove events by

```
const { provider: ethereum } = provider;
ethereum.on('accountsChanged', someFunction}; 
ethereum.off('accountsChanged', someFunction};
```

Comment: Thanks for this example. I was struggling with the way to listen with a Web3Provider instance. I checked this page https://docs.ethers.io/v5/concepts/best-practices/#best-practices and I tried to listen for accounts change like this `provider.on('accountsChanged', (accounts) => { console.log(accounts) })` but It was not working I had to do: `provider.provider.on(...)`. Do you know why it works with the `network` event ?

Comment: @AdrienG I believe because the 'network' event is an event on the ethers Web3Provider object. The 'accountChanged' event is on the window.ethereum object so you have to access it by provider.provider.on.

Comment: That makes sense ! thanks for your explanation ;)

Comment: Where can I find a list of events `ethers.js` supports? Searching `accountsChanged` in their documentation does not find anything at all, lol.

Comment: @Qwerty ethers just wraps a web3Provider, like window.ethereum. So you can still access all the expected EIP-1193 events by accessing provider.provider.ethereum. Now, ethers.js has some events of their own which can be found here https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--event-methods. You can register your "accountsChanged" handler without ethers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, glad to see some talk of it, I really wish Ethers would be explicit about this and state that they DO NOT handle certain events.

The way I have them working is to target the actual MetaMask provider itself. The syntax when using ethers should be something like

```js
Provider["provider"].on( event, callback )
```

Hope it helps!